# How to repeat SIGALRM?

Tags: c, timer, signals

I want to repeatedly set up a SIGALRM and wait until it goes off, then do it again. In my handler function I have:

```
void handler(int signum)
{
    struct itimerval timer;
    struct sigaction sa; 

    sa.sa_handler = handler;

    timer.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
    timer.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
    timer.it_value.tv_sec = 1000;

    sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa, 0);
    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &timer, 0);

    printf("pause for me\n");
    pause();
}
```

and in my main I have:

```
int main(void)
{
    handler(0);
    return 0;
}
```

However, all it does is repeat twice then stalls. I want it to continue repeating. What's the problem?

Comment: Is is safe to use `setitimer` from a signal handler? But is is probably ok here.

Comment: But `timer_settime()` is [ok](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`struct sigaction` has several fields which you are not initializing.  The stack garbage you happen to get the first few times works and then you hit a case where it does not and your handler is not installed.  You should test the `sigaction()` return.  When you get `-1` print a message including `errno`.

You should call `sigaction()` once (from `main()` or similar).  It will "stick" if you don't set the `SA_RESETHAND` flag.  Then your other existing code will probably work.

For more accurate repeating timing you should take advantage of `struct itimerval`'s `it_interval` which lets you set the *next* timer value so it will commence immediately when the current one fires.